# how to disable predefined cronjob?

Tags: cron

Is it safe (or is there a better way) to disable a cronjob that came with Ubuntu than to just remove the respective file out of the cron.* directory? In this particular case, I want to deactivate the fstrim-stuff as I have a configuration with two SSDs (a Samsung 850 EVO and some Kingston SSD that came with my notebook as a cache for the pre-installed HDD that I replaced with said Samsung) and want to have complete control over what gets TRIMmed and what doesn't...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you examine `/etc/crontab`, you'll find it uses `run-parts` to run the daily/weekly/etc. cronjobs (via `anacron`):

```
$ grep run /etc/anacrontab 
1   5   cron.daily  run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
7   10  cron.weekly run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly    15  cron.monthly    run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly
```

And [by default](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/run-parts.8):

```
run-parts  runs  all  the  executable  files  named  within constraints
described  below,  found  in  directory  directory.   Other  files  and
directories are silently ignored.

If neither the --lsbsysinit option nor the --regex option is given then
the names must consist entirely of ASCII upper- and lower-case letters,
ASCII digits, ASCII underscores, and ASCII minus-hyphens.
```

Therefore, to disable a given job, you can either:

- remove the execute permissions from it (`sudo chmod -x /etc/cron.daily/foo`)
- rename it to include a `.` or other character that `run-parts` usually dislikes

So:

```
sudo chmod -x /etc/cron.weekly/fstrim
```